# creating archive with pear Archive_Tar

Tags: php, tar

I'm creating a tar archive with the following function

```
public static function packDirectory($path, $outpath) {
    require_once 'Archive/Tar.php';

    $obj = new Archive_Tar($outpath);
    $obj->setErrorHandling(PEAR_ERROR_PRINT);

    $handle=opendir($path);
    $files = array();

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        $files[] = $path . '/' . $file;
    }

    $obj->create($files);
}
```

Path is something like `folder1/folder2/folder3/`. It creates an archive like the following

```
folder1/folder2/folder3/fileA
folder1/folder2/folder3/fileB
folder1/folder2/folder3/fileC
folder1/folder2/folder3/subfolder/fileD
```

I want that to be

```
fileA
fileB
fileC
subfolder/fileD
```

How tha can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [createModify method](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar/docs/latest/Archive_Tar/Archive_Tar.html#methodcreateModify) - it takes two more parameters than Archive_Tar's create method. To be complete, these three parameters are:

- $p_filelist - array of filenames
- $p_add_dir - string/path to be prepended to the filenames.
- $p_remove_dir - string/path to be removed from the filenames.

I changed your packDirectory method slightly, to include a third parameter of what to remove from the filenames. It looks like this:

```
<?php
class Packer {

    public static function packDirectory($path, $outpath, $stripPath = '') {
        require_once 'Archive/Tar.php';

        $obj = new Archive_Tar($outpath);
        $obj->setErrorHandling(PEAR_ERROR_PRINT);

        $handle=opendir($path);
        $files = array();

        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
                continue;
            }

            $files[] = $path . '/' . $file;
        }

        if ($stripPath === '') {
            $obj->create($files);
        } else {
            $obj->createModify($files, '', $stripPath);
        }
    }
}

Packer::packDirectory(
    "folder1/folder2/folder3", 
    "Packer.tar", 
    'folder1/folder2/folder3'
);
?>
```